# How to get static page content from DXA in spring controller?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2, spring

I am new to Tridion and learning DXA framework for my project.

I want to know how can I get page content from DXA framework for particular page request in a spring controller.

Can I use `pageController or ContentProvider` class. 
  Please help to understand how to use DXA framework in spring MVC project.

Comment: can you add more information in your question specific to your scenario , DXA's `PageController` already gets the `PageModel` for all page requests using requestPath and `ContentProvider`, check code of these two classes,  that should be helpful .

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you have understanding of basic flow of DD4T based content model where Component Template is directly connected with component view and Page Template is directly connected with Page view in your MVC based application.

DXA 1.2 come up with a ready-made website solution in Java. If you setup the DXA website code and debug the whole application you can understand the overall content flow. For more detail on architecture and content flow, you can go through documentation available in SDL Docs [site](http://docs.sdl.com/) and other blogs available on DXA. To start with DXA this [blog](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/30/dxa-java-kickstart-environment) can help you.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh for valid input, i need to do some stuff in HTTP Request in spring controller before passing the request to DXA frame. Whether there is any option do to this.

Comment: Which kind of stuff do you want to do in Http request? You can check EntityController, PageController if you can do your stuff there..